# send message from server to all connected clients

Tags: java, messaging

How can i send a message from server to all connected clients using sockets or how can i send message from server to any specific client. I have the concept of how to do it like i have to make a list of all the clients connected to server and then by iterating each client i can send message but i will be thankful if any one can help me by code.I have searched many codes but i didn't get any considerable help from them  Code shouldn't be GUI based. Thanks in advance.Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: it depends on your server architecture!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `java.net.ServerSocket`, you could keep a HashMap of all client connections using the following:

```
Map<Integer, java.net.Socket> clients = new HashMap<Integer, java.net.Socket> ();
```

### Caching a Client

Now, whenever you receive a new client connection to your server you can add the new client to the map:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();

// Add the socket to a HashMap
clients.put(socket.getPort(), socket);
```

### When you want to send a message to all of your clients:

Iterating through all your clients:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();

    java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);

    // Sending the response back to the client.
    // Note: Ideally you want all these in a try/catch/finally block
    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    bw.write("Some message");
    bw.flush();
}
```

### Notes:

- You will want a way to purge clients from the HashMap; especially if your server is long-lived.
- Ideally, you will want to put all the I/O code (to the clients) in a try/catch/finally block

Comment: As `socket.getLocalPort()` will always return the same value, you can't use it as a key in a Map of all connected clients.

Comment: @EJP You are correct. I changed my answer to `socket.getPort()`

Comment: Thankyou so much @MichaelMarkidis

Comment: Sir i have got this method could you please help me in sending that message to a specific client of my own choice @MichaelMarkidis

Comment: @zeeshannisar it depends on how you want to identify the client. What identifier do you want to use to filter out the client?